# jquery read in HTML file and return the file as an object-why doesn't it work?

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if maybe this code doesn't work because you can't return a JQuery object from a function. This code doesn't work:

```
var HTML_FILE_URL = '/Solutions1.htm';
var strAll = $.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function (data) {
                      var fileDom = $(data);
                      return fileDom;
                });
 $("#qapagediv").append(strAll.html());
```

However, this code does work:

```
 var strAll = $.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function (data) {
         var fileDom = $(data);
         $("#qapagediv").append(fileDom);
         return fileDom;
  });
```

Comment: Take a look at the `.done()` method of [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `$.get` returns a `$.Deferred().promise()`, not the return value from your callback.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for $.get() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ it doesn't return the value of a callback. Functions with callbacks for success generally run asynchronously.

You could perform your task inside of the callback function

```
$.get(...).done(function(data) { 
    var strAll = $(data);
    $("#qapagediv").append(strAll);
});
```

To do things like your first example you need to run your AJAX request synchronously. Synchronously means it's completed before execution moves on to the next line.

```
var strAll = null;
$.ajax({
    url: HTML_FILE_URL
    success: function(result) {
        strAll = $(data);
    },
    async: false
});
...
$("#qapagediv").append(strAll.html());
```